# Screen sharing with remote desktop (remote monitor)

Tags: networking, multiple-monitors, remote-desktop

We have a big screen here, in our meeting room, attached to a desktop computer. The primary use of this screen is for Powerpoint presentations.

**I want to share the screen of any computer, not just the connected one, without cables, via network. Something like a "remote second monitor". Is this possible?**

I also look for the simplest solution possible, without any work on the hosting machine; something like "the client connects to the server, and the screen is displayed on the monitor".

Comment: How about a remote desktop connection?  If you don't want wires then connect wirelessly.

Comment: Yes, but for a desktop connection, the host (the machine connected to the screen) needs to connect to the client (my laptop). I want this process reversed: the client connects to the host, and the host shows the shared screen on the monitor.

Comment: Since you want this to be wireless it would require hardware that supports `WiDi` and `Miracast`.

Comment: Yes, but only if I'm trying to connect directly to the monitor. That's not the case, since I have a desktop connected to this screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can use [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/products/remotecontrol.aspx).

TeamViewer - the All-In-One Software for Remote Support and Online Meetings

TeamViewer is a proprietary computer software package for remote control, desktop sharing, online meetings, web conferencing and file transfer between computers. Versions are available for the Microsoft Windows, OS X, Linux, iOS, Android, Windows RT and Windows Phone operating systems. It is also possible to access a machine running TeamViewer with a web browser.[8] While the main focus of the application is remote control of computers, collaboration and presentation features are included.

Or you can use [VNC](https://www.realvnc.com/)

VNC® access software for desktop and mobile platforms.

VNC enables you to remotely access and control your devices wherever you are in the world, whenever you need to. VNC has a widespread user base — from individuals to the world's largest multi-national companies — utilizing the technology for a range of applications.

Comment: Both solutions are great, and I'm already familiarized with them, but both solutions requires "work" on the hosting machine, like "the host machine connects to the client and display the client screen on the monitor". I need this proccess reverted, like "the client connects to the host, and the host display the client screen on the monitor".

Comment: With teamviewer you can Connect to the Host machine and then Switch Sides. Which means that you will be running a TeamViewer instance on the Host machine with predefined password, and anyone has its id will be able to connect to it and then Switch Sides to it. So When this will happen, the Monitor that will be attached to the Host machine will show your Computer's Screen. However this needs a bit of configuration in order the host machine to go immediately in Full SCreen after Switch Sides

Comment: Sounds nice! Will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like [**zoom**](http://zoom.us).  You can share screens or just an application either direction.  You can make annotation, record what is going on and etc.  There is a free version that allows meeting up to 40 minutes.  it is a very lightweight installer.  Here is a list of [**features**](http://zoom.us/pricing).

If you don't like this option there are plenty of web meeting applications/vendors out there.